# Django Forms: possible to update only some parameters?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

Lets say I have a very simple Model,

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    foo = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    bar = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
```

a ModelForm

```
class EntityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Entity
```

and I am executing the following code:

```
#preparation
entity = Entity()
entity.foo = 'foo'
entity.bar = 'bar'
entity.save()

params = {
    'foo': 'oof'
}

form = EntityForm(params, instance=entity)
entity = form.save()
```

The value for entity.bar is lost.
What is the proper way of updating a model partially using forms?

Answer (score 0):

You could override form's `save` method to update only changed fields:

```
class EntityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Entity

    def save(self, commit=True):
        from django.forms import save_instance

        if self.instance.pk is None:
            fail_message = 'created'
        else:
            fail_message = 'changed'
        return save_instance(self, self.instance, self.changed_data,
                             fail_message, commit, construct=False)
```

Comment: That looks promising but doesn't work. The existing value of entity.bar is set to empty string. Printing self.changed_data at the beginning of the new save method gives me: ['foo', 'bar']. But I didn't change entity.bar.

Comment: And we if pass `initial` to form like this: `form = EntityForm(params, instance=entity, initial={'foo': entity.foo, 'bar': entity.bar})`. If this work it can be done inside form constructor.

Comment: `changed_data` is generated only if initial was given.